# Unable to find OLEDB provider in data source list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to add an ADO.net Entity Data Model in my project. I am having accdb file. When I am trying to add this in the data source, unable to get the OLEDB provider on the list.

[image]

I am already having Microsoft Access engine provider. What I am missing on my system. Please help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can choose other, then choose Data provider '.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB'. Also, you can refer to [Change the provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-connections?view=vs-2019#change-the-provider).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will give you the connection as a drop down item, but these code samples show you a couple ways to connect to MS Access.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OleDbConnection oledbCnn ;
            OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter ;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string sql = null;
            int i = 0;

            connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;";
            sql = "Your SQL Statement Here like Select * from product"; 

            oledbCnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                oledbCnn.Open();
                oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbCnn);
                oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " -- " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                }
                oledbAdapter.Dispose();
                oledbCnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OleDbConnection oledbCnn ;
            OleDbCommand oledbCmd ;
            string sql = null;

            connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;";
            sql = "Your SQL Statement Here like Select * from product";

            oledbCnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                oledbCnn.Open();
                oledbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn);
                OleDbDataReader oledbReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (oledbReader.Read ())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(oledbReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + oledbReader.GetValue(1) + " - " + oledbReader.GetValue(2));
                }
                oledbReader.Close();
                oledbCmd.Dispose();
                oledbCnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is an explanation about [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) related to [OleDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB)?

Comment: My vision is not what it used to be.  I actually thought the question was related to  ODBC.

Comment: I want it for ADO.NET Entity Data Model, this thing I am able to do. I want the auto model class to be created via EF.